# Repeated division by 2 method - where is my mistake?

Tags: binary

[image: Here is my task]

I keep getting a different result than from an online calculator. -
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=353+to+binary

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost at the end of your binary conversion. Just add the last 1 (the quotient $2/2$) and read it backwards. Therfore you obtain
$$353=(101100001)_2$$

Comment: Thank's, that's the answer. I didn't realize that it's backwards.

Answer (score 0):

Just write the successive quotients

$$353,176,88,44,22,11,5,2,1$$ and assign the binary digits $0/1$ to even/odd, from least significant to most significant.

$$101100001.$$